# WPF: when I maximize my window, controls do not resize

Tags: wpf, controls, resize, state

So when I run my program, and hit the maximize button up in the right corner, my window resizes, but all my controls stay the same size in the page...

If I click a corner or edge of my window and drag to resize, the controls re-size as I would expect.

I have tried playing with the onStateChange handler, but it has not done anything.

Anyone have any ideas how to make controls resize when I maximize my window?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you creating your controls in xaml? could you post that?

Comment: no, just things like treeviews/richtextboxes and stuff

Comment: could you post your code then?

Answer (score 0):

When you click on a control, do you see that each side has either a black solid dot or a black circle? Click on those, and solid dots are what side the control is pinned to and if you pin it to all sides it will resize as the window resizes.

Comment: they are all anchored to all sides (well, the ones i want to be atleast lol)